# AWS Load Balancer alternative in Express+React app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have a MERN Stack application hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have a static IP address and 2 listeners ( load balancer ) for ports 80 and 443 to make my app work on https only and not http.

So far everything works perfectly fine but I was wondering is there a way I can remove the load balancer but behavior remains the same? It's not a high demand app and I don't want to spend 16$ a month just for a balancer.

I am open to make any changes to the app itself or my AWS configs.

Not sure if I need to provide more information, so please let me know if I missed anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the load balancer and going to have single instance. You can follow the below documentation from AWS to allow HTTPS in Single instance

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html